# Simple neural network implementation in Python

Tags: python, ai, machine-learning, neural-network

A simple neural network I wrote in Python without libraries. I avoided implementing it in matrix form because I sought to get a basic understanding of the way NN's work first. For that reason I'm strongly favoring legibility over efficiency. I tried to keep my code readable and pyhonic, any style feedback would be particularly appreciated.

A quirk about this design is it does back propagation on a per training example basis and uses momentum to try and avoid over fitting to specific examples.
Also I realized I never added base values to the neurons, it seems to work alright with out them but if anyone has a more in depth understanding of why you'd want them I'd be curious to hear about that.

```
import math
import random

import data

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return x * (1.0 - x)

def loss(x,y):
    return sum([(a-b)**2 for (a,b) in zip(x,y)])

class Neuron():
    learning_rate = 0.015
    momentum_loss = 0.03

    def __init__(self, input_neurons):
        self.weights = [random.uniform(-1,1) for _ in range(input_neurons)]
        self.momentum = [0 for _ in range(input_neurons)]

    def forward(self, inputs):
        dot = sum([x*y for (x,y) in zip(inputs, self.weights)])
        self.output = sigmoid(dot) 
        return self.output

    def backpropagate(self, inputs, error):
        error_values = list()
        gradient = error * sigmoid_prime(self.output)
        for i, inp in enumerate(inputs):
            self.nudge_weight(i, gradient * inp)
            error_values.append(self.weights[i]  * gradient)
        return error_values

    def nudge_weight(self, weight, amount):
        change = amount * Neuron.learning_rate
        self.momentum[weight] += change
        self.momentum[weight] *= (1 - Neuron.momentum_loss)
        self.weights[weight] += change + self.momentum[weight] 

class Network():
    def __init__(self, topology):
        self.layers = list()
        for i in range(1,len(topology)):
            self.layers.append([Neuron(topology[i-1]) for _ in range(topology[i])])

    def forward(self, data):
        output = data
        for layer in self.layers:
            output = [neuron.forward(output) for neuron in layer]
        return output

    def backpropagate(self, data, output, target):
        error_values = [tval - output for (tval, output) in zip(target, output)]
        for i in range(len(self.layers)-1,0,-1): 
            layer_output = [neuron.output for neuron in self.layers[i-1]]
            error_values = self.backpropagate_layer(i, error_values, layer_output)
        self.backpropagate_layer(0, error_values, data)

    def backpropagate_layer(self, layer, error_values, inputs):
        next_errors = list()
        for neuron, error in zip(self.layers[layer], error_values):
            bp_error = neuron.backpropagate(inputs,error)
            if not next_errors:
                next_errors = bp_error
            else:
                next_errors = [a+b for a,b in zip(next_errors,bp_error)]
        return next_errors
```

The full source code for project including the data base and some other testing code can be found here: [https://github.com/RowanL3/Neural-Network](https://github.com/RowanL3/Neural-Network/tree/d1e36d5e8277b44040aae6ffdad94fd4a21235c3)

Answer (score 4):

A more pythonic way of writing `self.momentum = [0 for _ in range(input_neurons)]` would be `self.momentum = [0]*input_neurons`